# Could a moon of a mini-neptune around a red dwarf harbour life?

Tags: life, natural-satellites, gas-giants, red-dwarf

I am planning a game where on could control evolution on an alien world.

I was thinking red dwarf as per here [Habitable Planet around Red Dwarf](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/10542)

To my understanding three questions arise:

- Tidal lock
- Radiation
- Sunspots

Could a parent body (think small gas giant) be tidally locked and a moon then freely rotate? Could the magnetic field of a parent body protect a moon from a sun without the parent radiating too much?

I don't know what to say about sunspots though.

Then about the parent body itself:

Is the formation of the mini-neptune so close to a red dwarf impossible? Would its gravity wreck eveything?

Comment: When wondering if X can support life, one should always keep in mind that the only reason we know that the answer to "Can the Earth support life?" is "Yes" is that we're here to see it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for the [World Building SE](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I can move it there. I was just thinking if there was something obviously wrong.